# remove debut and end string character

Tags: java

I have the following string "Welcome to Java", and I need to extract the characters inside the quotes, is there a built in method that does that ? Just like the `trim` method removes spaces before and after a string.

Please note that the " are part of the string.

Comment: You mean `trim()` rather than `split()`? If you know the first and last chars are always quotes, you could use `substring(1, s.length() - 1)`

Comment: Yes I did mean trim(), and I completely forgot about substring, thanks a lot:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the first comment suggested, I just used the `substring()` method to deal with it. Thanks for all the answers.

Answer (score 2):

You can use StringUtils from apache commons lang, but you need to escape the quotes first.

Here is the example.

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String str = "\"Welcome to Java\"";
        String res = StringUtils.substringBetween(str, "\"", "\"");

        System.out.println(res);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex can do that, too!

```
String str = "\"Welcome to Java\"";
str = str.replaceAll("(\")(.*?)(\")", "$2");

System.out.println(str);
```

The regex pattern `(\")(.*?)(\")` means that split str to three part, first and third is a sing quote, second is the rest of the original string. And the replaceAll method second args means that we only need the second part.